# Empty response from National Weather Service web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I wrote a process that retrieved data from the National Weather Service web service.  It was working nicely for several years until Valentines Day.  Now the call keeps getting an empty response error.  I've contacted the National Weather Service and they so far have not been able to provide any suggestions except to say they recently changed to https.  I tried creating a new simple test project with a new reference to their https URL and I still get the empty response error.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

I set a web reference to:

https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl

Here's the code I am testing and it still fails with the empty response error:

```
    private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal nLatitude = (decimal)30.32;
        decimal nLongitude = (decimal)-81.55;
        DateTime dEndTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dStartTime = dEndTime.AddHours(-2);
        XmlDocument oXmlDocument = GetXmlDocument(nLatitude, nLongitude, dStartTime, dEndTime);
    }
    private XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(decimal nLatitude, decimal nLongitude, DateTime dStartTime, DateTime dEndTime)
    {
        XmlDocument oXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            gov.weather.graphical.ndfdXML oWebProxy = new gov.weather.graphical.ndfdXML();
            gov.weather.graphical.productType oProductType = gov.weather.graphical.productType.timeseries;
            gov.weather.graphical.unitType oUnitType = gov.weather.graphical.unitType.e;
            gov.weather.graphical.weatherParametersType oWeatherParametersType = new gov.weather.graphical.weatherParametersType();
            oWeatherParametersType.appt = true;         // Apparent Temperature
            oWeatherParametersType.icons = true;        // Conditions Icons
            oWeatherParametersType.dew = true;          // Dew Point Temperature
            oWeatherParametersType.maxt = true;         // Daily Maximum Temperature
            oWeatherParametersType.mint = true;         // Daily Minimum Temperature - no response
            oWeatherParametersType.pop12 = true;        // 12 Hourly Probability of Precipitation
            oWeatherParametersType.precipa_r = true;    // Liquid Precipitation Amount
            oWeatherParametersType.rh = true;           // Relative Humidity
            oWeatherParametersType.sky = true;          // Cloud Cover Amount
            oWeatherParametersType.snow = true;         // Snow Amount
            oWeatherParametersType.temp = true;         // Temperature
            oWeatherParametersType.wdir = true;         // Wind Direction
            oWeatherParametersType.wgust = true;        // Wind Speed Gust
            oWeatherParametersType.wspd = true;         // Wind Speed
            oWeatherParametersType.wwa = true;          // Watches, Warnings, and Advisories
            oWeatherParametersType.wx = true;           // Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity

            string sXmlData = oWebProxy.NDFDgen(nLatitude, nLongitude, oProductType, dStartTime, dEndTime, oUnitType, oWeatherParametersType);
            oXmlDocument.LoadXml(sXmlData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string sMessage = e.Message;
            sMessage = "Error: " + sMessage;
        }
        return oXmlDocument;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the c# web reference I changed ours from:

http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl

to:

https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl

I had to change a few of the parameters for my call to "string" format but the xml it returned seemed to be in the same format as the other url I used.

Hope this helps.

My call is now:

```
ndfdXML.NDFDgenByDay(currentLoc.latitude, currentLoc.longitude, DateTime.Now, "7", "e", "12 hourly");
```

To get the 7 day in my area.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That new URL works for me, too.  How did you find that?  I traded emails with their tech support and I got nowhere with them.

Comment: I kept googling around and came here somehow: https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php

from there I clicked the link for "View the WSDL for the service".

after it opened up the xml to view I looked at the address in my browser's URL and thought I would give it a try.

Comment: Excellent investigation.  I'll try to remember that approach.