# Soap error: "The HTTP request is prohibited with the 'Anonymous' client authentication scheme."

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm looking for a SOAP service to consume and get some wheater information.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355212/empty-response-from-national-weather-service-web-service) pointted me to use the wsdl: https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl

I add the reference to my C# Visual Studio Project, and it generated the current app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ndfdXMLBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ndfdXMLBinding1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://graphical.weather.gov:443/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ndfdXMLBinding"
                contract="Wheater.ndfdXMLPortType" name="ndfdXMLPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is my call in c# code:

```
var w = new Wheater.ndfdXMLPortTypeClient();
var s = w.NDFDgenByDay((decimal)38.99,
                       (decimal)77.01,
                       new DateTime(2017, 08, 01),
                       "1",
                       "m",
                       "12 hourly");
txtBox.Text = s;
```

But when I call it, I'm getting the error message: "The HTTP request is prohibited with the 'Anonymous' client authentication scheme."

What I am doing wrong?